# How to attach a file to a MailItem

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate creation of an email with a user required to press Send so it can be checked. I can get the mail item created with a 'To' list and such, however when I try to add an attachment I get an error.

```vb
Sub EmailReportX(ByVal MailTo As String, AttachFilename As String, AttachFilePath As String, SubjectDate As String)
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMailItem As Object
    Dim strAtt As String
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMailItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    strAtt = AttachFilePath & AttachFilename
    
    With objMailItem
        .To = MailTo
        .Subject = "Seymour Horst Daily Completions Report " & SubjectDate
        .body = "Morning," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Daily completions report for review" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Regards" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Tim C"
        .Attachments.Add = strAtt
        .display
    End With
    Debug.Print strAtt
End Sub
```

Comment: `AttachFilePath` has a trailing `\ `? Else you need to add it when assigning `strAtt`.

Comment: Show the error you got and what Debug.Print strAtt shows. Probably the path of the file is not correct. Be sure all the trailings are ok and the the extension of the file is included in the full path

Comment: i think its .Attachments.Add(strAtt) if i remeber rightly

Comment: All great checks thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`.Attachments.Add()` is a method and thus does not require the equals sign.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add

so use it like this.

```
With objMailItem
    .To = MailTo
    .Subject = "Seymour Horst Daily Completions Report " & SubjectDate
    .body = "Morning," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Daily completions report for review" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Regards" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Tim C"
    .Attachments.Add strAtt
    .display
End With
```

Comment: Oh!  thank you so much :-)  that's great and works, problem solved!!